# How do I make friends in high school, a place where people casually swear a lot, when I'm easily offended?

Tags: high-school

My classmates were all kind and easy-going in elementary school. When I entered middle school, that all changed. Kids started swearing, sticking up middle fingers, casually insulting each other, and talking trash about other kids behind their backs. I'm emotionally sensitive. In 8th grade, couldn't walk in the hallways without getting my feelings hurt for even 10 seconds. I'm going to 9th grade in late August, and I want to be prepared. As far as I know, the kids' behavior will just get worse! They'll start doing drugs and having underage, unprotected sex. I'm afraid that I won't fit in and make friends. Being bad is pretty much a requirement to be accepted in modern teen culture. E.g. in middle school, a kid called me "pussy" because I said that I didn't want to get into fights. How do I, someone who's easily offended, survive in the high school social system full of "edgy" teenagers?

EDIT: They usually don't mean what they say. Kids make fun of their friends, and nobody is harmed. However, it hurts my feelings when they make fun of me. I want to be able to interact with them without getting offended.

I feel that it's unfair to make other kids stop cussing just because I don't like it. My goal is to adapt and learn to "brush off" mean remarks.

Comment: This seems....somewhat hyperbolic.

Comment: Considering yourself "the only good person" and everyone else around you "immoral" is an excellent way to be ostracized in any location.

Comment: @Erik That's not what I meant. I edited the question now.

Comment: That's already a bit better. :)

Comment: @Ash Nope. Realistic!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like you may be asking an **intra**personal question. "*However, it hurts my feelings when they cuss at me. That's the problem I want to solve.*" Unfortunately questions focused on how to better or change yourself are off-topic here. If you can rewrite the question to be about interpersonal interactions it may be a better fit.

Comment: I see your latest edit changed the wording I quoted. But even still, you're asking us for a way to change the way **you** feel. Questions here should focus on the behaviors and feelings of others--such is the nature of interpersonal skills. Perhaps you could ask how to talk to them about reducing the cursing around you? Or talk to them about reducing the mean jokes if you're easily offended? Those questions would be better for this site.

Comment: Being concerned about the language you use, and the language others use when you are trying to get on with people and make friends is absolutely an interpersonal skill!

Comment: @Astralbee but that is not what the question is about. Learning how to brush off mean remarks is not IPS. OP is neither trying to stop them from cussing nor do I get the impression he wants to adapt himself to start cussing too.

Comment: @Cashbee Correct. He wants to make friends, with those two conditions, and deal with people who *do* swear without feeling offended himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having been good kid in all of elementary school, I totally understand where you're coming from. Going to middle school was tough at first. I learnt to cuss and swear, yes, but that wasn't the thing that eventually got me "accepted" into my clique of friends; it was being *sarcastic*. And no, I don't mean sarcastically saying everything so everyone thinks you're putting off the conversation. What I mean is being smart and twist your words in a way such that it gets the message across *and* it's a tad humorous.

---

This example conversation I'm gonna cite is probably not one that you would use (because you would feel it is offensive) but I'm citing it so you know what I'm trying to get across in this answer.

> Friend: Oh my, I've got so much homework to finish up on.
>
> Me: Homework? What's that? Can it be eaten? (I said this sarcastically to subtly 'laugh' at him and bring the point across that I've got no homework for the day)
>
> Friend: Oh sure, it's delicious! Maybe you can eat it up for me, then I'll just tell my teacher tomorrow that **my dog ate my homework.** (this roasted me so badly but it was a good comeback and I laughed at it)

Again, you'd probably feel offended if your friend said it to you, which is why this example *may not be the best one*, but it's all good fun and laughter after sarcastic exchanges take place. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You have to find other "outcasts". It's true for making friends anywhere, normally it's finding people who share the same interests or have similar outlooks to life and other topics. But in your particular case you might want to find people who share more or less the same moral outlook and behavior. In other words, the "outcasts"